# Unable to inject <form> into popover content

Tags: javascript, bootstrap-4, popover, bootstrap-popover

I'm trying to show a popover with content that I get from an API via AJAX. The content contains some HTML tags, including `<form>` with a `<textarea>` and a `<button>`, `<br/>`s, `<a>`s and `<time>`s.

The problem I'm facing is that some of them aren't added at all (not displayed, and not shown in the code when I inspect), while others are perfectly fine.

Now here's a few thing that I've ruled out:

- The data sent by the API is fine, it shows perfectly if I inject somewhere else
- The AJAX call works fine aswell

If you have any idea where the problem is, or any lead to search, thanks!

Here's a demo of the same code I'm using:

```js
$(function() {
  var content = '<form><textarea></textarea></form>';
  button = $("a#myButton")
  button.popover({
    'html': true,
    'content': content, // content that contains a <form> and <textarea, it should not injected in the popover
    'trigger': 'click',
    'placement': 'bottom'
  });
  button.parent().append(content); // but it can perfectly be added elsewhere
  $("a#myOtherButton").popover({
    'html': true,
    'content': 'hello<br/><br/>there', // this content should be working perfectly fine
    'trigger': 'click',
    'placement': 'bottom'
  });
});
```

```html
<link href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.4.1/css/bootstrap.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.16.0/umd/popper.js"></script>
<script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.4.1/js/bootstrap.js"></script>


<div id="myDiv">
  <a id="myButton" class="btn btn-primary" style="color:white;">This is a button</a>
  <a id="myOtherButton" class="btn btn-primary" style="color:white;">This is another button</a>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to add the option 'sanitize': false

```js
$(function() {
  var content = '<form><textarea></textarea></form>';
  button = $("a#myButton")
  button.popover({
    'html': true,
    'sanitize': false,
    'content': content, // content that contains a <form> and <textarea, it should not injected in the popover
    'trigger': 'click',
    'placement': 'bottom'
  });
  $("a#myOtherButton").popover({
    'html': true,
    'content': 'hello<br/><br/>there', // this content should be working perfectly fine
    'trigger': 'click',
    'placement': 'bottom'
  });
});
```

```html
<link href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.4.1/css/bootstrap.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.16.0/umd/popper.js"></script>
<script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.4.1/js/bootstrap.js"></script>


<div id="myDiv">
  <a id="myButton" class="btn btn-primary" style="color:white;">This is a button</a>
  <a id="myOtherButton" class="btn btn-primary" style="color:white;">This is another button</a>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks that works well! That's not the most secure thing, but it's only used internally and I'm controlling also the HTML that's sent to the AJAX, so I'd say it's fine.